# Mod Rewrite with 3 parameters and text

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to write a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file, 
I readed tutorials but always fails.

What I want is:

`domain.com/en/111/page-title` ->redirects to-> `domain.com/viewPage.php?language=en&id=111`

I dont need the `page-title` parameter, only the language and id

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do *not* actually want a redirection rule, but an internal rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2}])/(\d+)/ /viewPage.php?language=$1&id=$2 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).